# Restful - How to set restful ws method parameters

Tags: java, rest

I have a rest service method:

```
@GET
@Path("/searchMekan")
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
public List<Mekan> searchMekan(@PathParam("mesafe") int mesafe,
        @PathParam("lokasyonEnlem") String lokasyonEnlem,
        @PathParam("lokasyonBoylam") String lokasyonBoylam) {

     ....................
}
```

But I don't know how to call this method from the client side, and I actually don't know how to set method parameters from the client side. Could you please create a client for this method? (I use java at the client side.)

Here is my client;

```
public class MekanSearchServisTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();
    Client client = Client.create(config);
    WebResource service = client.resource(getBaseURI());

    System.out.println(service.path("servis").path("mekansearchservis")
            .path("searchMekan")

            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get(String.class));
}

private static URI getBaseURI() {
    return UriBuilder.fromUri("http://localhost:7001/KampanyaDuyuruServis")
            .build();
}
```

}

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing site. If you can demonstrate effort by showing an attempt at the client side code, then we can help you out.

Answer (score 3):

You've missed parts of the URL. It should include your parameters since you've declared them as PathParam:

```
@Path("/seachMekan/{mesafe}/{lokasyonEnlem}/{lokasyonBoylam}")
```

this way you'll be able to call the service by

```
http://yoursite/seachMekan/12/lokasyonEnlem/lokasyonBoylam
```

Comment: Thank u Artem, I know, I have to put my parameters into my URl, but how ? could you show me on this line service.path("servis").path("mekansearchservis")
            .path("searchMekan")

            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get(String.class)

Comment: See second part of my answer: just make them part of your URL

Comment: I got below error artem;  com.sun.jersey.api.client.UniformInterfaceException: GET http://localhost:7001/KampanyaDuyuruServis/servis/mekansearchservis/searchMekan/10/53.4534534/67.766868 returned a response status of 404 Not Found

Comment: I set my url like;  service.path("servis").path("mekansearchservis")
    .path("searchMekan")
    .path("10").path("53.4534534").path("67.766868")
    .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get(String.class)

Comment: Also you can try calling the URL you have in the browser: http://localhost:7001/KampanyaDuyuruServis/servis/mekansearchservis/searchMekan/12/53.4534534/67.766868

Comment: Sometimes you can find WADL for your service http://localhost:7001/KampanyaDuyuruServis/servis/mekansearchservis/searchMekan/?_wadl - this will show if your service is running and what are the expected parameters

Comment: I have changed my service method like ;   `@GET
 @Path("/searchMekan")
 @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
 public List<Mekan> searchMekan(@QueryParam("mesafe") String mesafe,
   @QueryParam("lokasyonEnlem") String lokasyonEnlem,
   @QueryParam("lokasyonBoylam") String lokasyonBoylam) {` and my client like ; `service.path("servis").path("mekansearchservis")
    .path("searchMekan")
    .queryParam("mesafe", "10")
    .queryParam("lokasyonEnlem", "ali")
    .queryParam("lokasyonBoylam", "cevik")
    .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get(String.class)` now everything is OK

Comment: I'm pretty sure though that you can make it work with path parameters as well :)